# My score record refers to the topic which I didn't ask and didn't answer

Tags: support, reputation

Noticed my score was credited -1 due to downvote. Funny thing the record references the topic which I didn't ask and never answered. Bug or something?

[image: screenshot]

Topic: [Splitting a large table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139688/splitting-a-large-table/139696#139696)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The -1 would be associated with a downvote [you cast on someone else's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down). From that link:

> **What happens when I vote down?**
>
> When you vote down, you are nudging that content "down" the page, so it will be seen by fewer people. Voting down answers is not something we want you to take lightly, so it is not free.
>
> - Downvotes remove **2** reputation from the post owner.
> - Downvotes on *answers* remove **1** reputation from you, the voter.
> - Downvotes on *questions* are **free**. ([Why?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/))
> - You can vote **30** times per UTC day. You get an additional **10** votes on questions only. ([Why?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/))

If you want to check your complete reputation calculation, see [your personal reputation report](https://dba.stackexchange.com/reputation).